# update not working with pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

Firstly, I find a document and update value state to 1 in DB with findandmodify() method. Then I use the document to do something. After that, I want to update the document's state to 2 with its object id, and the method I use is update().
However, after such operation, the state value didn't change to 2. Here is a brief version of my codes:

```
try:
    print 'update...'
    db.Tuser.update({'_id':obj_id},  # obj_id is a bson object, it's the object id of the document
                    {'$set':{'state': 2}})
    print 'update done'
except Exception as e:
    print 'update failed: %s' % str(e)
```

The output is:
    update...
    update done

By the way, this happens when I run it on 8 PCs, and only 2 of them can update successfully. While when I run it singly, it works well.

Comment: if you can share some more information about obj_id (it's type for example) it will be easier to debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try some basic debugging steps - Does this return anything?

```
db.Tuser.find({'_id':obj_id},
                {'$set':{'state': 2}})
```

Is obj_id a string or a bson object?

```
type(obj_id)
```

If it's a string you will need to convert it to a bson object

```
import bson
obj_id = bson.ObjectId(obj_id)
```

Comment: I've tried using a variable to keep the update's return, and using logging module to print the variable as a log. But it seems there is no loggs. By the way, I run the codes in 4 PCs, one of them can update successfully.

Comment: But find() can't do update operation. And obj_id is a bson object.

Comment: I'm asking you if `find` returns anything. What's most likely happening is that update cannot find the correct document to update, and you can verify this by seeing if `find` returns anything.